# Why is the class CanvasPane not included in the Java API?

Tags: java, jpanel

** Why is the class CanvasPane not included in the Java API?.

```
   import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.geom.*;

    /**
     * Class Canvas - a class to allow for simple graphical 
     * drawing on a canvas.
     * 
     * @author Michael Kolling (mik)
     * @author Bruce Quig
     *
     * @version 2008.03.30
     */

    public class Canvas
    {
        private JFrame frame;
        private CanvasPane canvas;
        private Graphics2D graphic;
        private Color backgroundColor;
        private Image canvasImage;

        /**
         * Create a Canvas with default height, width and background color 
         * (300, 300, white)
         * @param title  title to appear in Canvas Frame     
         */
        public Canvas(String title)
        {
            this(title, 300, 300, Color.white);        
        }

        /**
         * Create a Canvas with default background color (white).
         * @param title  title to appear in Canvas Frame
         * @param width  the desired width for the canvas
         * @param height  the desired height for the canvas
         */
        public Canvas(String title, int width, int height)
        {
            this(title, width, height, Color.white);
        }

        /**
         * Create a Canvas.
         * @param title  title to appear in Canvas Frame
         * @param width  the desired width for the canvas
         * @param height  the desired height for the canvas
         * @param bgClour  the desired background color of the canvas
         */
        public Canvas(String title, int width, int height, Color bgColor)
        {
            frame = new JFrame();
            canvas = new CanvasPane();
            frame.setContentPane(canvas);
            frame.setTitle(title);
            canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
            backgroundColor = bgColor;
            frame.pack();
        }

        /**
         * Set the canvas visibility and brings canvas to the front of screen
         * when made visible. This method can also be used to bring an already
         * visible canvas to the front of other windows.
         * @param visible  boolean value representing the desired visibility of
         * the canvas (true or false) 
         */
        public void setVisible(boolean visible)
        {
            if(graphic == null) {
                // first time: instantiate the offscreen image and fill it with
                // the background color
                Dimension size = canvas.getSize();
                canvasImage = canvas.createImage(size.width, size.height);
                graphic = (Graphics2D)canvasImage.getGraphics();
                graphic.setColor(backgroundColor);
                graphic.fillRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
                graphic.setColor(Color.black);
            }
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        /**
         * Provide information on visibility of the Canvas.
         * @return  true if canvas is visible, false otherwise
         */
        public boolean isVisible()
        {
            return frame.isVisible();
        }

        /**
         * Draw the outline of a given shape onto the canvas.
         * @param  shape  the shape object to be drawn on the canvas
         */
        public void draw(Shape shape)
        {
            graphic.draw(shape);
            canvas.repaint();
        }

        /**
         * Fill the internal dimensions of a given shape with the current 
         * foreground color of the canvas.
         * @param  shape  the shape object to be filled 
         */
        public void fill(Shape shape)
        {
            graphic.fill(shape);
            canvas.repaint();
        }

        /**
         * Fill the internal dimensions of the given circle with the current 
         * foreground color of the canvas.
         */
        public void fillCircle(int xPos, int yPos, int diameter)
        {
            Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(xPos, yPos, diameter, diameter);
            fill(circle);
        }

        /**
         * Fill the internal dimensions of the given rectangle with the current 
         * foreground color of the canvas. This is a convenience method. A similar 
         * effect can be achieved with the "fill" method.
         */
        public void fillRectangle(int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height)
        {
            fill(new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height));
        }

        /**
         * Erase the whole canvas.
         */
        public void erase()
        {
            Color original = graphic.getColor();
            graphic.setColor(backgroundColor);
            Dimension size = canvas.getSize();
            graphic.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
            graphic.setColor(original);
            canvas.repaint();
        }

        /**
         * Erase the internal dimensions of the given circle. This is a 
         * convenience method. A similar effect can be achieved with
         * the "erase" method.
         */
        public void eraseCircle(int xPos, int yPos, int diameter)
        {
            Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(xPos, yPos, diameter, diameter);
            erase(circle);
        }

        /**
         * Erase the internal dimensions of the given rectangle. This is a 
         * convenience method. A similar effect can be achieved with
         * the "erase" method.
         */
        public void eraseRectangle(int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height)
        {
            erase(new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height));
        }

        /**
         * Erase a given shape's interior on the screen.
         * @param  shape  the shape object to be erased 
         */
        public void erase(Shape shape)
        {
            Color original = graphic.getColor();
            graphic.setColor(backgroundColor);
            graphic.fill(shape);              // erase by filling background color
            graphic.setColor(original);
            canvas.repaint();
        }

        /**
         * Erases a given shape's outline on the screen.
         * @param  shape  the shape object to be erased 
         */
        public void eraseOutline(Shape shape)
        {
            Color original = graphic.getColor();
            graphic.setColor(backgroundColor);
            graphic.draw(shape);  // erase by drawing background color
            graphic.setColor(original);
            canvas.repaint();
        }

        /**
         * Draws an image onto the canvas.
         * @param  image   the Image object to be displayed 
         * @param  x       x co-ordinate for Image placement 
         * @param  y       y co-ordinate for Image placement 
         * @return  returns boolean value representing whether the image was 
         *          completely loaded 
         */
        public boolean drawImage(Image image, int x, int y)
        {
            boolean result = graphic.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
            canvas.repaint();
            return result;
        }

        /**
         * Draws a String on the Canvas.
         * @param  text   the String to be displayed 
         * @param  x      x co-ordinate for text placement 
         * @param  y      y co-ordinate for text placement
         */
        public void drawString(String text, int x, int y)
        {
            graphic.drawString(text, x, y);   
            canvas.repaint();
        }

        /**
         * Erases a String on the Canvas.
         * @param  text     the String to be displayed 
         * @param  x        x co-ordinate for text placement 
         * @param  y        y co-ordinate for text placement
         */
        public void eraseString(String text, int x, int y)
        {
            Color original = graphic.getColor();
            graphic.setColor(backgroundColor);
            graphic.drawString(text, x, y);   
            graphic.setColor(original);
            canvas.repaint();
        }

        /**
         * Draws a line on the Canvas.
         * @param  x1   x co-ordinate of start of line 
         * @param  y1   y co-ordinate of start of line 
         * @param  x2   x co-ordinate of end of line 
         * @param  y2   y co-ordinate of end of line 
         */
        public void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
        {
            graphic.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);   
            canvas.repaint();
        }

        /**
         * Sets the foreground color of the Canvas.
         * @param  newColor   the new color for the foreground of the Canvas 
         */
        public void setForegroundColor(Color newColor)
        {
            graphic.setColor(newColor);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the current color of the foreground.
         * @return   the color of the foreground of the Canvas 
         */
        public Color getForegroundColor()
        {
            return graphic.getColor();
        }

        /**
         * Sets the background color of the Canvas.
         * @param  newColor   the new color for the background of the Canvas 
         */
        public void setBackgroundColor(Color newColor)
        {
            backgroundColor = newColor;   
            graphic.setBackground(newColor);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the current color of the background
         * @return   the color of the background of the Canvas 
         */
        public Color getBackgroundColor()
        {
            return backgroundColor;
        }

        /**
         * changes the current Font used on the Canvas
         * @param  newFont   new font to be used for String output
         */
        public void setFont(Font newFont)
        {
            graphic.setFont(newFont);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the current font of the canvas.
         * @return     the font currently in use
         **/
        public Font getFont()
        {
            return graphic.getFont();
        }

        /**
         * Sets the size of the canvas.
         * @param  width    new width 
         * @param  height   new height 
         */
        public void setSize(int width, int height)
        {
            canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
            Image oldImage = canvasImage;
            canvasImage = canvas.createImage(width, height);
            graphic = (Graphics2D)canvasImage.getGraphics();
            graphic.drawImage(oldImage, 0, 0, null);
            frame.pack();
        }

        /**
         * Returns the size of the canvas.
         * @return     The current dimension of the canvas
         */
        public Dimension getSize()
        {
            return canvas.getSize();
        }

        /**
         * Waits for a specified number of milliseconds before finishing.
         * This provides an easy way to specify a small delay which can be
         * used when producing animations.
         * @param  milliseconds  the number 
         */
        public void wait(int milliseconds)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // ignoring exception at the moment
            }
        }

        /************************************************************************
         * Inner class CanvasPane - the actual canvas component contained in the
         * Canvas frame. This is essentially a JPanel with added capability to
         * refresh the image drawn on it.
         */
        private class CanvasPane extends JPanel
        {
            public void paint(Graphics g)
            {
                g.drawImage(canvasImage, 0, 0, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why it should be? I mean its a BlueJ extension class, AFAIK. Similar questions may come to the mind regarding StringUtils, or NumberUtils. IMHO, these two really qualifies to be there in the original Java API. :)

Comment: Thanks Vinegar and one more thing when I compile the following class in BlueJ I get the error "can not find symbol-class CanvasPane" can you tell me how to correct this

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

/**
 * Creates a Frame and fills it with a Canvas.
 * 
 * @author (Varuna Seneviratna) 
 * @version (June 05 2009)
 */
public class MyFrame
{
   
    private JFrame frame;
    private CanvasPane canvas;
}

Comment: Aha... If you see the code above of class Canvas, then you will know that at the bottom there is CanvasPane class, which is defined as private. So, it means you will not have access to that class from outside, for example your MyFrame class. I hope you are getting my point.

Comment: Thanks Vinegar, I didn't see it

Answer (score 0):

One **huge** reason is that it has one of the worst named methods I have ever seen in a Java class:

```
public void wait(int milliseconds)
```

Try calling wait(100) on it and watch it work without synchronisation *and obviously do something completely different from `java.lang.Object.wait(long)`*. This would be a nightmare to do in production.

What on earth is such a method doing in a class named `Canvas`?