# BlueJ: cannot find class CanvasPane

Tags: java, bluej

When I try to use class CanvasPane in BlueJ, it throws a compilation error saying "cannot find symbol - class CanvasPane" even when I add these imports:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Possible repost of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954053/why-is-the-class-canvaspane-not-included-in-the-java-api. The Answer is hopefully there.

Answer (score 0):

the below packages doesn't contain `CanvasPane`

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
```

Checking this [URL](http://www.bluej.org/resources/classes/Canvas.java), `CanvasPane` is a private inner Class in `BlueJ.java` you can't import it.Otherwise you can define your own `canvasPane` and embed it on your class:

```
 public class MyClass{

     private CanvasPane myCanvasPane;

        public class CanvasPane extends JPanel
        {
            public void paint(Graphics g)
            {
                g.drawImage(canvasImage, 0, 0, null);
            }
        }
    }
```